# Replace words in a string including plural variations with apostrophes

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, apostrophe

I want to link matches for specific words in a sentence. Overall this is easy, and sample code could go like this:

```
$words = array("Facebook", "Apple");
$text = "Is Facebook's vr hardware better than Apple's current prototype?";
foreach($words as $w) {
    $pattern = '/' . $w .'\b/i';
    $link = '<a href="/blah/' . strtolower($w) . '">' . $w . '</a>';
    $text = preg_replace($pattern, $link, $text);
}
print $text;
```

However I would like to catch variations of words that have `'s` (*apostrophe-s*).

To do that I need to search for the two possible variations (with and without the `'s`), but the outcome also affects what text used in the replacement.

I'm drawing a blank on how to pro-actively used `preg_match` and then alter `preg_replace` based on the outcome. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the optional `?` quantifier and parenthesis.

`$pattern = '/' . $w .'(\'s)?\b/i';`

should match either version.

now, to use the match in your replacement, you can add an extra set of parenthesis, like this:

`$pattern = '/(' . $w .'(\'s)?)\b/i';`

then insert the matched string into your replacement, like this:

`$link = '<a href="/blah/' . strtolower($w) . '">$1</a>';`

the $1 in the replacement string will be replaced with whatever the outer parenthesis of the match contains.